# compare objects in views.py of 2 different models objects in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, compare

I am trying to compare 2 objects (skills of a job posting such as web development, marketing, etc to the same skills of a logged-in user), if matched will display that job posting.

The goal is to display multiple job postings that match the user. Currently, jobmatch.html does not display any jobs.

Thank you for taking the time!!

**views.py**

```
from apps.job.models import Job
from apps.userprofile.models import User_profile

def match_jobs(request):
    match_jobs = {}
    for job in Job.objects.all():
        if job.product_management == User_profile.product_management:
            match_jobs['product management'] = job
        elif job.web_development == User_profile.web_development:
            match_jobs['web development'] = job
        elif job.user_experience == User_profile.user_experience:
            match_jobs['user experience'] = job
        elif job.marketing == User_profile.marketing:
            match_jobs['marketing'] = job
        elif job.finance == User_profile.finance:
            match_jobs['finance'] = job

    return render(request, 'jobmatch.html', match_jobs)
```

**Job.models.py**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    requirements = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    product_management = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    web_development = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_experience = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    marketing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**User.models.py**

```
class User_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    resume = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='resume')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Enter full name')
    relevant_background = models.TextField()
    product_management = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    web_development = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    user_experience = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    marketing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    finance = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**jobmatch.html**

```
            {% for job in match_jobs %}
                <div class="colum is-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">{{ job.title }}</p>
                                    <p class="subtitle is-6">{{ job.created_at }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="content">
                                {{ job.location }}

                                <br>

                                <a href="{% url 'job_detail' job.id %}">View</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redesign your models.

Store all the skills inside a  separate table.

```
class Skill(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50) # example web development
```

Now you can link your job and user profile model with Skill model through ManyToMany relationship.

```
class Job(models.Model):
  ......
  skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
 
class UserProfile(models.Model):
.........
  skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

Now you can get matched jobs with this.

```
 user_skills = request.user.userprofile.skills.all()
 matched_jobs = Job.objects.filter(skills__in=user_skills)
```

Comment: The other advantage of this approach is that you can then extend it by storing the importance of the skill for the job or the level of skill of the person on the table that manages the many to many relationship to do matches that are flexibile than does/doesn't have a skill.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have a branch using a similar method with ManyToManyField(Skill) but how do I create specific skills like web dev, etc? I am trying to make boolean fields so they can be checkboxes and then match them.  

```class User_profile(models.Model):
 user_skills = models.ManyToManyField('UserSkills', related_name='user_profiles', blank=True)
 
 
class UserSkills(models.Model):
 web_development = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
 ```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Skill` model to create any skills you want and also relate them to jobs and users using `ManyToManyField`. This will make it easy to add, update or remove any skills.

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Job(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)    
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    requirements = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, related_name='as_job_skill')

class User_profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    resume = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='resume')
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Enter full name')
    relevant_background = models.TextField()
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, blank=True, related_name='as_user_skill')
```

You can also find the matching jobs for users very easily.

```
def match_jobs(request):
    user_profile = request.user.userprofile
    matched_jobs = Job.objects.filter(skills__in=user_profile.skills.all()).distinct()
    return render(request, 'jobmatch.html', matched_jobs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried ManyToManyField but I got stuck. How can I make multiple instances of name? I had made them separate before: 
```class UserSkills(models.Model):
 product_management = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
 web_development = models.BooleanField(...```

Comment: You can register the skill model to admin site and then add the skills over there. In order to select a skill for a user or a job do just do `<job instance/user_profile instance>.skills.add(<skill instance>)`. and use `remove` method to remove those added skills. And to access jobs with a particular skill just do `<skill instance>.as_job_skill.all()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have iteration by dict keys now. You have to do something like: `{% for job in match_jobs.values %}` or `{% for job_identifier, job in match_jobs.items %}`

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for but neither worked. Maybe there's something else off in my code?